# Intentionally high CPU usage, GCD, QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, and spindump

Tags: xcode, grand-central-dispatch, cpu-usage

I am developing a program that happens to use a lot of CPU cycles to do its job. I have noticed that it, and other CPU intensive tasks, like iMovie import/export or Grapher Examples, will trigger a spin dump report, logged in Console:

> 1/21/16 12:37:30.000 PM kernel[0]: process iMovie[697] thread 22740 caught burning CPU! It used more than 50% CPU (Actual recent usage: 77%) over 180 seconds. thread lifetime cpu usage 91.400140 seconds, (87.318264 user, 4.081876 system) ledger info: balance: 90006145252 credit: 90006145252 debit: 0 limit: 90000000000 (50%) period: 180000000000 time since last refill (ns): 116147448571
>
> 1/21/16 12:37:30.881 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.ReportCrash[705]) Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.ReportCrash
>
> 1/21/16 12:37:30.883 PM ReportCrash[705]: Invoking spindump for pid=697 thread=22740 percent_cpu=77 duration=117 because of excessive cpu utilization
> 1/21/16 12:37:35.199 PM spindump[423]: Saved cpu_resource.diag report for iMovie version 9.0.4 (1634) to /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/iMovie_2016-01-21-123735_cudrnaks-MacBook-Pro.cpu_resource.diag

I understand that high CPU usage *may* be associated with software errors, but some operations simply require high CPU usage. It seems a waste of resources to watch-dog and report processes/threads that are expected to use a lot of CPU.

In my program, I use four serial GCD dispatch queues, one for each core of the i7 processor. I have tried using QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, and spin dump recognizes this:

> Primary state:   31 samples Non-Frontmost App, Non-Suppressed, Kernel mode, Thread QoS Background

The fan spins much more slowly when using QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND instead of QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, and the program takes about 2x longer to complete. As a side issue, Activity Monitor still reports the same % CPU usage and even longer total CPU Time for the same task.

Based on Apple's Energy Efficiency documentation, QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND seems to be the proper choice for something that takes a long time to complete:

> Work takes significant time, such as minutes or hours.

So why then does it still complain about using a lot of CPU time? I've read about methods to disable spindump, but these methods disable it for all processes. Is there a programmatic way to tell the system that this process/thread is expected to use a lot of CPU, so don't bother watch-dogging it?